# How to make a Button displaying a drop down list using GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to using GWT 2.4 to make a widget just like below: a button, when clicking it can show a drop-down list under it. This picture is from Google's new Blogger system.

Anyone could shed some light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `MenuBar` widget with a single menu item (being the button) having a submenu (the dropdown menu).

Or you could use a `Button`, and from within a `ClickHandler` you'd show a `PopupPanel` containing a vertical `MenuBar` [*relative to*](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#showRelativeTo%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject%29) the button (which you'd set as an [*auto-hide partner*](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#addAutoHidePartner%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29))